# What are the best practices to shoot similar angles and sizes of product photographs?

Tags: product-photography, studio-setup

The issue is that after I do the shoot and want to re-do the shots, I do not know where to exactly position the camera like how near it is, the angle, and etc. It creates images that are not standardized and does not look too neat when you line them up. How do people know how to replicate a product shot?

Below are samples of different images:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

When a movie crew wants an actor to be able to stand in exactly the same spot each time, they put a mark on the floor. They then actually measure the distance, not just rely on autofocus. One of the camera assistant's jobs is to record all data associated with every single shot & make sure it is filed with the footage.

Do the same.

To allow for the fact that your backdrop sheet may not be identical each time, make a special template of cardboard or wood, with positions for the camera & front two edges of a box. Mark visible frame edges & centre line-up for the camera angle & write any relevant height information on the template.
Whether you do this by actually cutting out a sturdy 'frame' that your objects & camera can be aligned to, or on paper with subtle dots that can be removed in post will probably depend on how frequently you need to do this & how similar your range of objects is.

So long as you also note your lighting positions/settings in a similar manner & record your camera settings too [in each session's notes, in the session folder] then you can recreate a shot days, weeks or months later.